# Вопрос по ошибкам

Tags: symfony, php, silex

Данный код (Silex Framework) принимает файл, закидывает его в папку и записывает в базу. Проблема в том, что если файл больше лимита сервера, то не выбрасывает исключение, где ошибка?

```
    $app->post('/upload', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
    try {
        $file = $request->files->get('upload');
        $hash = hash_file('adler32', $file);
        if($file->move(__DIR__.'/../files', $hash)){
            $app['db']->insert('files', array(
                'filename' => $file->getClientOriginalName(),
                'ip' => ip2long($request->getClientIp()),
                'filehash' => $hash,
                'filesize' => $file->getClientSize(),
                'time' => time(),
            ));
            return $app->json(array('filename'=>$file->getClientOriginalName(),'fileid'=>$app['db']->lastInsertId()));
            }
        }
    catch (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileException $e) {
        return $app->json(['error'=>$e->getMessage()]);
    }
});

http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html
```

Comment: Каких "лимитов"? В коде нет проверки ни на какие лимиты. метод UploadedFile::move бросает исключение если файл [не может быть перемещен](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.php#L228). Лимиты для вашего приложения вы должны проверить сами, либо выставить соответствующие настройки веб-сервера.

Comment: лимитов, заданных в настройках веб-сервера. я пробовал через условие $file->isValid(), но если файл не загружен, то и объекта UploadedFile нету. Пробовал FileNotFoundEception, но тоже не подходит